# JMH benchmarking avoid jvm optimization

Tags: java, performance, performance-testing, microbenchmark, jmh

I am trying to write jmh benchmarks.

I am came across various blogs mentioning pitfalls in jmh benchmarking. The common example are

1. this code

```
int sum() {
   int a =7;
   int b = 8;
   return a+b;
}
```

will be optimised to

```
int sum() {
return 15;
}
```

2. this code

```
int sum(int y) {
   int x = new Object();
   return y;
}
```

will be optimised to

```
int sum(int y) {
   return y;
}
```

i.e. removing non used object initialisation.

### But this list is no where extensive to what all sort of optimisation jvm will do.

Below is the problem i am facing.

Lets say there are few methods and here is how call graph looks like

```
int methodA(CustomObjectA a) {
   //do something 
   methodB(a);
   //do something
   return returnValueA;
}

int methodB(CustomObjectA a) {
   //do something 
   methodC(a);
   //do something
   return returnValueB;
}

int methodC(CustomObjectA a) {
   //do something
   return returnValueC;
}
```

And we will try to benchmark methodA. By Passing CustomObjectA created in state object. But

1. from JVM perspective methodC is always called with same reference, wouldn't it optimise methodC to return same returnValueC all the time?
2. Why would it not do this?
3. How can we make sure this optimisation will not be done? by passing different reference every time using   @State(Scope.Thread)?
4. Is there any exhaustive list to explain what all optimisation might be possible?

Comment: in `int methodC(CustomObjectA a)` why do you pass `a` as argument if you are not doing anything with it?

Comment: i am doing something with a

Answer (score 2):

Are you saying that you want to test `methodA` and all of those other methods are `private` and this is how the call chain looks like? If so, `JMH` here is irrelevant - what optimizations are going to be applied, will still be applied to that code. It is also quite impossible to tell what optimizations might happen in the end, since they are *a lot* on the `JVM`, and also depend on a lot of other factors like operating system, CPU, etc; so an "extensive list" simply can't exist.

Depending on what you do in that `//do something` in each method, that code could be elided or not, for example. Look at this simplified example:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 5)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 5)
public class Sample {

    private static final int ME = 1;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(Sample.class.getSimpleName())
                .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int methodOne(CustomObjectA a) {
        simulateWork();
        return 42;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int methodTwo(CustomObjectA a, Blackhole bh) {
        bh.consume(simulateWork());
        return 42;
    }

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class CustomObjectA {

    }

    private static double simulateWork() {
        return ME << 1;
    }

}
```

The difference is that in method `methodTwo`, I use a so called `Blackhole` (read [this](https://github.com/openjdk/jmh/blob/master/jmh-samples/src/main/java/org/openjdk/jmh/samples/JMHSample_09_Blackholes.java) for more details), while in `methodOne`, I do not. As a result `simulateWork` is eliminated from `methodOne`, as the results show:

```
Benchmark         Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
Sample.methodOne  avgt   25  1.950 ± 0.078  ns/op
Sample.methodTwo  avgt   25  3.955 ± 0.120  ns/op
```

On the other hand, if I even slightly change the code to have the smallest possible side effects:

```
@BenchmarkMode(Mode.AverageTime)
@OutputTimeUnit(TimeUnit.NANOSECONDS)
@Warmup(iterations = 5, time = 5)
@Measurement(iterations = 5, time = 5)
public class Sample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Options opt = new OptionsBuilder()
                .include(Sample.class.getSimpleName())
                .build();

        new Runner(opt).run();
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int methodOne(CustomObjectA a) {
        simulateWorkWithA(a);
        return 42;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int methodTwo(CustomObjectA a) {
        return simulateWorkWithA(a) + 42;
    }

    @Benchmark
    public int methodThree(CustomObjectA a, Blackhole bh) {
        bh.consume(simulateWorkWithA(a));
        return 42;
    }

    @State(Scope.Thread)
    public static class CustomObjectA {
        int x = 0;
    }

    private static int simulateWorkWithA(CustomObjectA a) {
        return a.x = a.x + 1;
    }

}
```

the elimination of `simulateWorkWithA(a)` in `methodOne` will not happen:

```
Benchmark           Mode  Cnt  Score   Error  Units
Sample.methodOne    avgt   25  2.267 ± 0.198  ns/op
Sample.methodThree  avgt   25  3.711 ± 0.131  ns/op
Sample.methodTwo    avgt   25  2.325 ± 0.008  ns/op
```

Notice that there is almost no difference between `methodOne` and `methodTwo`.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `extensive list simply can't exist.`. in that case here are my problems, 1. lets say there is a static method, and we pass same variable to it over and over again, will it not cache the response value for same input param (PropertyUtils.getProperty(Object bean, String name) to be very specific)? 2. In the case of nested method invocation, I can not change source code to pass blackhole all the way right? 3. Is benchmarking only way to see what all optimisations might be happening? because in that case, it becomes tough to ascertain someone else's benchmarks are correct.

Comment: @bestwishes for (1), yes, it might optimize to that. so what? For (2) - yes, you can't. But look at the second example that I provided and understand it: even if there are optimization performed, they will still happen in a non-perceivable way. For (3) : I don't  really understand your query. The overall point here is that : yes, a lot of optimizations happen, allocations might be elided, variables might be inlined, etc - it does not matter. If you want to measure `methodA` - measure it the way it is.

Comment: `yes, it might optimise to that. so what?` >>> but on product the probability of this happening would be lower right? hence whatever benchmark i will be reporting would be wrong. `it does not matter. If you want to measure methodA - measure it the way it is.` >> but on production the benchmark would not hold true, as things will be more random there( rather than fixed set of inputs. ) and whatever optimisation are performed in benchmark would not be done in production environment.

Comment: @bestwishes it would not be "wrong", it is still correct, but not in accordance to whatever you see in your production. Mind that `JMH` has different modes, like in `C1` jit compiler only, or a cold start also